Error when I log in to desktop

I think it is something with snaps but I am not sure.
How do I know what is the problem?

Which Ubuntu version?

Xubuntu noble 24.04 x86_64

I also have such popup window in Xubuntu 24.04. It says that an application restarted.

If you click the Report Problem button you will see more information about your problem.

when I click 'Report Problem' it just closes the window

I removed everything in /var/crash/ with sudo rm filename.crash
And that fixed it

Press Report problem and follow instructions ...
It might not tell you the exact error/problem, but developers at least will be notified so a fix can be implemented.
